# How to deal with layouts in PyQt4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I want to display welcome label in middle of frame, how can I do that? It seems like layout problem as I googled but I haven't got final solution.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
                super(Window, self).__init__()
                palette = QPalette()
                palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background, QBrush(QPixmap("Login page.jpg")))
                self.setPalette(palette)
                self.setWindowTitle("Login Frame")
                self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('logo.png'))
                self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
                self.setFixedSize(500, 300)
                self.addWidgets()

        def addWidgets(self):
                self.lblWelcome = QLabel("Welcome to Railway e-Ticketing System", self)
                self.lblWelcome.move(100,30)
                wcFont = QFont("Open Sans", 25)
                self.lblWelcome.setFont(wcFont)

                self.lblUid = QLabel("User ID:", self)
                self.lblUid.move(100,80)

                font = QFont("Open Sans", 10)
                self.lneUid = QLineEdit(self)
                self.lneUid.setFont(font)
                self.lneUid.setFixedHeight(25)
                self.lneUid.setFixedWidth(200)
                self.lneUid.move(225, 80)


                self.lblPass = QLabel("Password:", self)
                self.lblPass.move(100, 130)

                self.lnePass = QLineEdit(self)
                self.lnePass.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
                self.lnePass.setFixedHeight(25)  
                self.lnePass.setFixedWidth(200)
                self.lnePass.move(225, 130)

                self.lblInvalid = QLabel("",self)
                self.lblInvalid.move(100, 180)

                self.btnLogin = QPushButton("Login",self)
                #btnLogin.resize(btnLogin.sizeHint())
                self.btnLogin.move(175, 230)
                self.btnLogin.clicked.connect(self.authenticate)
                #self.authenticate()

                self.btnReg = QPushButton("Register", self)
                self.btnReg.move(300, 230)
                #btnReg.clicked.connect(register)

                self.show()

        def authenticate(self):
                uid = self.lneUid.text()
                upass = self.lnePass.text()
                if(len(uid.strip()) == 0 or len(upass.strip()) == 0):
                        palette = QPalette()
                        palette.setColor(QPalette.Foreground, Qt.darkRed)
                        self.lblInvalid.setPalette(palette)
                        self.lblInvalid.setText("*Invalid credentials .")
                else:
                        self.lblInvalid.setText("")





def main():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        LoginWin = Window()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `QMainWindow` which [already has a layout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#details) with a central widget, a toolbar, a menu bar etc. The right way to use it is to define a central Widget, and put all your label and buttons in it. You didn't, so your label is not displayed properly.

But for your login frame, you clearly don't need all of this. You just need a `QWidget`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui  

class LoginFrame(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginFrame, self).__init__()
        ...

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = LoginFrame()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Your code should work with a `QWidget`, but I would still advise reading about box layout. Right now, you're using absolute positioning, which means you have to manually place your widget at a precise position, and you can't resize your window.

A box layout would be more flexible, and practical. For example you can use [QFormLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qformlayout.html#details) for the userID and password.

More about layouts on the [ZetCode tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/layoutmanagement/)